# Image float left of centred text, then all floats removed for mobile displays

Tags: html, css

Just cannot seem to get this to work!

I'd like an image to float left, and the text to the right of it to be centered in the remaining space.

And for smaller displays <480px, the image to no longer float, to be centered and smaller (100px) - and the text to be centered on a line below.

[This image should illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yTdw.png)

```
<div class="quiztopheader">
    <div class="quiztopimage"><img src="myimage.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="quiztitle"><u>This is the line 1</u>
        <br/><div class="quizsubtitle">And this is line 2 not underlined</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.quiztopheader {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.quiztopimage{
    padding: 10px 25px 0px 5px;
    float: left;
    min-width:150px;
    width:150px;    
}

.quiztitle {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 150px;

    width: (100%-150px);

    float:center;
}
.quizsubtitle {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .quiztopheader {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        overflow: auto; 
    }
    .quiztopimage {
        width:100%;
        clear: left;
        clear: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .quiztitle {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 24px;

    }
    .quizsubtitle{
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you resize to smaller screens you need to remove the left margin on `quiztitle`, as this is preventing the text from being perfectly centered.

```
.quiztitle {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/RKbKeq)

```css
.quiztopheader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.quiztopimage {
  padding: 10px 25px 0px 5px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.quiztitle {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 150px;
  width: (100%-150px);
  float: center;
}

.quizsubtitle {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .quiztopheader {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .quiztopimage {
    width: 100%;
    clear: left;
    clear: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .quiztitle {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .quizsubtitle {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="quiztopheader">
  <div class="quiztopimage"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></div>
  <div class="quiztitle"><u>This is the line 1</u>
    <br/>
    <div class="quizsubtitle">And this is line 2 not underlined</div>
  </div>
</div>
```